# How catch iframe resize event from inside the iframe (iframe and the page - same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I try to listen from inside of iframe to changes of iframe width/height with:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    alert('1 on inside iframe');
});
```

or:

```
$(window.parent).find('iframe').resize(function(){
    alert('2 on inside iframe');
});
```

but nothing happens when iframe size changes. (I need a cross-browser solution: IE7, Chrome, Firefox, Safari.)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(body).resize(function(){
    alert('on inside iframe');
});
```

> Edit :

in html

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">
```

Comment: In Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, the onresize event is fired only when the size of the browser window is changed.http://help.dottoro.com/ljorlllt.php

Comment: This does not seem correct. w3Schools suggests onResize only works on the <body>. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Comment: should be $("body").resize
i.e add quotes around body

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `resize()` handler from the `parent` document on the `iframe`:

```
$('iframe').resize(function() {} );
```