# Check the presence of Disqus plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I installed the Disqus plugin, and my WP theme now presents a problem at height of sidebar.

Disqus loads the iframe after the content of my theme. For this reason the JS script that sets the height of the sidebar doesn't see that new section, because is added before the calculation.

I need to fire again the THEME.siteHeight(); function in theme/js/init.js after the load of Disqus.

In that file, there's this section:

```
$( window ).load( function() {
        CANOS.retina( 'desktop-logo', 'retina-logo' );
        CANOS.retina( 'footer-desktop-logo', 'footer-retina-logo' );
        CANOS.siteHeight();
    });


})( jQuery );
```

I need to put a custom function here:

```
$( window ).load( function() {
        CANOS.retina( 'desktop-logo', 'retina-logo' );
        CANOS.retina( 'footer-desktop-logo', 'footer-retina-logo' );
        CANOS.siteHeight();
    });


    if disqus is loaded {
        CANOS.siteHeight();
    }


})( jQuery );
```

Obviously I need to find a way to check the presence of Disqus ("if disqus is loaded" doesn't work).

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe try adding a resize handler on the iframe?http://stackoverflow.com/a/9484560/2103033

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a disqus script is loaded with a function like

```
function hasDisqus() {
    var url = "disqus";
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = scripts.length; i--;) {
        if (scripts[i].src.match(/url/g)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can do

```
if(hasDisqus())
```

Bit of a dirty solution, but might work for you